# AlertBox - Error occured while executing doInBackground()

Tags: java, android

```
 public class IdAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

 AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainClass.this).create();

    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
      .
       .
      alertDialog.setTitle("Reset...");
            alertDialog.setMessage("R u sure?");
             alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                   //here you can add functions

                } });

   alertDialog.show();
      .
    .}
```

This gives Runtime error
E/AndroidRuntime(16606):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method doInBackground is used to do background tasks. To update the UI in AsyncTask use onProgressUpdate method. Refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate(Progress...)

Answer (score 1):

Hi you should execute the dialog in the onPostExecute, onPreExecute or onProgressUpdate method of AsyncTask to update the UI.
Not in doInBackGround.